# Perl: function to trim string leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: perl

Is there a built-in function to trim leading and trailing whitespace such that `trim(" hello world ") eq "hello world"`?

Comment: FYI: string equality in Perl is tested by the operator `eq`.

Comment: A bit of clarification on all the asnwers you got: `s/^\s+|\s+$//g;` vs `s/^\s*//; s/\s*$//;` The latter is the (ever so slightly) more idiomatic way to do this, as starting the regex engine over is actually faster than the alternation, in this case. You can read more about this on Jeffrey Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions. (Unless this was fixed in some newer version of Perl, in which case someone please correct me!)

Comment: Coming from a Java and .NET background, I'm almost shocked this isn't built into the language! THANKS ALL!

Comment: @landon9720, it somewhat is: Scalar::Util has trim, and is core since 5.7.3 - That's 2002!

Comment: Hugmeir, this is wrong, [see the answer of Ether](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4597937#4598148).

Comment: Comparison of even more functions: http://www.illusori.co.uk/perl/2010/03/05/advanced_benchmark_analysis_1.html http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript

Answer (score 99):

Here's one approach using a regular expression:

```
$string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g ;     # remove both leading and trailing whitespace
```

Perl 6 will include a trim function:

```
$string .= trim;
```

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28programming%29#Perl)

Comment: I look this up about once a month. Too bad I can't upvote it each time.

Answer (score 87):

This is available in [String::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Util) with the `trim` method:

<sup>Editor's note: `String::Util` is not a core module, but you can install it from [CPAN](http://cpan.org) with `[sudo] cpan String::Util`.</sup>

```
use String::Util 'trim';
my $str = "  hello  ";
$str = trim($str);
print "string is now: '$str'\n";
```

prints:

> string is now 'hello'

However it is easy enough to do yourself:

```
$str =~ s/^\s+//;
$str =~ s/\s+$//;
```

Comment: @mklement0 nor will it ever be. But this is not relevant, since everyone should be using modules from the CPAN.

Comment: why should everyone use modules from CPAN? It makes consistency difficult when using perl from your linux distribution (debian, redhat, ubuntu) combined with manually installed CPAN modules. It is much better if something can be done in perl using modules which are available as packages in linux distribution

Comment: @Marki555 modules available as packages in your linux distro *are* from CPAN -- they've just been repackaged. You can generally request a certain module to be packaged if it hasn't been done so already (the debian folks are particularly responsive and helpful).

Comment: I know they are also from CPAN... Yes, generally I can request a new pkg for debian, but it won't help me for my installed debian stable release... that's why I prefer packages modules, but use directly CPAN if really needed.

Comment: @Ether With all due respect, I really appreciate knowing that this is a non-core module. This post is talking about using a module in lieu of a fairly simple regex one-liner. If the module is core, I would be much more open to it. It is relevant in this case.

Comment: I would prefer the possessive \s++ over \s+ It is slightly more efficient, because it does not use backtracking. Although admittedly, this only matters if you invoke it an insane amount of times.

Answer (score 31):

There's no built-in `trim` function, but you can easily implement your own using a simple substitution:

```
sub trim {
    (my $s = $_[0]) =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    return $s;
}
```

or using [non-destructive substitution](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Non-destructive_substitution) in Perl 5.14 and later:

```
sub trim {
   return $_[0] =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//rg;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

According to [this perlmonk's thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=2258):

```
$string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

Answer (score 9):

Complete howto in the perfaq here:
http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-strip-blank-space-from-the-beginning-end-of-a-string-

Answer (score 4):

One option is [Text::Trim](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Trim):

```
use Text::Trim;
print trim("  example  ");
```

Answer (score 4):

For those that are using Text::CSV I found this thread and then noticed within the CSV module that you could strip it out via switch:

```
$csv = Text::CSV->new({allow_whitespace => 1});
```

The logic is backwards in that if you want to strip then you set to 1.  Go figure.  Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Apply: `s/^\s*//; s/\s+$//;` to it. Or use  `s/^\s+|\s+$//g` if you want to be fancy.

Answer (score 3):

I also use a positive lookahead to trim repeating spaces inside the text:

```
s/^\s+|\s(?=\s)|\s+$//g
```

Answer (score -3):

No, but you can use the `s///` substitution operator and the `\s` whitespace assertion to get the same result.

Comment: That would remove spaces between words, not just at either end of the string.

Comment: @DarenW: depends how you use it.