# Java like trim function for perl

Tags: perl, trim

Is there an [Java like](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) trim function for Perl.

I am looking for function in Perl that removes all the leading and trailing characters below 0x20, like in Java.

After calling the function on the following string.

```
my $string = "\N{U+0020}\N{U+001f}\N{U+001e}\N{U+001d}\N{U+001c}\N{U+001b}\N{U+001a}\N{U+0019}\N{U+0018}\N{U+0017}\N{U+0016}\N{U+0015}\N{U+0014}\N{U+0013}\N{U+0012}\N{U+0011}Hello Moto\N{U+0010}\N{U+000f}\N{U+000e}\N{U+000d}\N{U+000c}\N{U+000b}\N{U+000a}\N{U+0009}\N{U+0008}\N{U+0007}\N{U+0006}\N{U+0005}\N{U+0004}\N{U+0003}\N{U+0002}\N{U+0001}\N{U+0000}";
```

Only "Hello Moto" should be left.

The trim from [String::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Util#trim-string) only removes the first whitespace (\N{U+0020}).

Comment: `s/[\x00-\x1F]//g` removes all character below 0x20, but that's not what Java's String.trim does

Comment: Ok, i forgot to write that it removes only the leading and trailing characters in the range of \x00-\x1F, right? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perl: function to trim string leading and trailing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597937/perl-function-to-trim-string-leading-and-trailing-whitespace)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The traditional ASCII way was to use

```
$string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

(i.e. remove whitespace (`\s`) from the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string.

[U+001f](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f/index.htm) is not whitespace, it's a Control. You can use Unicode properties in regular expressions with `\p`:

```
my $drop = qr/[\p{Space}\p{Cc}]+/;
$whitespace =~ s/^$drop|$drop$//g;
```

Or, more verbose:

```
$drop = qr/[\p{White_Space}\p{Cntrl}]+/;
```

You should probably change the name of the variable.

Comment: `$string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;` You forgot the third slash to close the substitute.