# Why am I still getting newlines?

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I have the following code:

```
open INPUT, "input.txt";
my $line = "";
while (<INPUT>)
{
        $line = $_;
        $line =~  s/\s+^//;
        print $line;
}
```

But the output still includes all the newlines.  I have also tried `\v` and `\R`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl: function to trim string leading and trailing whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597937/perl-function-to-trim-string-leading-and-trailing-whitespace)

Comment: @JGreenwell How could it possibly be a duplicate?  I have given an extract of code that clearly contains an error pointed out by ruakh below.

Comment: Because your actual question is how do I remove the trailing whitespace and the regex that answers your question is in the linked question's answers (also includes a note on chomp vs. regex)

Comment: @JGreenwell That is not the question I asked.  I asked a question about a specific extract of code which was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\s+^/` means "one or more whitespace characters *before* the *start* of the string" — so it will never match.

If your goal is to remove *trailing* whitespace characters, then you need `$` rather than `^`:

```
    $line =~  s/\s+$//;
```

(And if your goal is really just to remove the trailing newline, then you should probably use [the built-in `chomp` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).)

Comment: @CJ7: That's . . . not a very helpful statement. I mean, obviously `chomp` works. It's not like it's been broken this whole time and no one has ever noticed. If you're having difficulty with it, you need to provide more information about how you're using it and what's going wrong.

Comment: I used `chomp $line` instead of the regex line above and it still outputted all the newlines.

Comment: @CJ7 Then either you changed the input record separator `$/` from the default, or your lines don't end in `$/`. To test, add `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $line;`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot `chomp` doesn't remove carriage return characters

Comment: @CJ7 Actually [it does if you're running on Windows](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines) or if you change the value of `$/`. If you're running on *nix but your file has Windows line endings, you have to either change `$/` before you `chomp` or use the regex ruakh showed.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: `$/` is set to `"\n"` by default on every platform. PerlIO changes the line endings to a simple newline on input, but if you use `chomp` on a string that ends in `"\r\n"` then you will be left with a carriage return, even on Windows

Comment: @Borodin Ah, I misunderstood that bit. Thanks for the explanation.